# What is the plural for Balance?

Tags: grammar, singular-vs-plural

I have read that the word "balance" can be both singular and plural, is that correct? Or is "balances" the only acceptable way to write it?

Thank you.

Comment: "I have read that..."  If you have read something somewhere.  you **must** say exactly where you read it.  Please edit your question to (1) give the source and (2) quote exactly what you read.

Comment: This question needs more context.  Please give the exact sentence that you're thinking of, because otherwise it is hard to give you an answer.

Answer (score 1):

In what way are you using the noun ***balance***?

A "balance" can be a scientic instrument used for weighing minute quantities.

That forms its plural in the usual way - ***The laboratory had several balances***.

It can also be an accountancy term e.g.for the balance on an account. Again the normal plural rule applies - ***There were large balances on some debtors' accounts***. But there is also a non-countable sense ***the books were out of balance***.

It is also a medical term, describing a person's ability not to fall over. That too is a non-countable use - and no plural applies. ***She lost her balance on the stairs***.

There may well be other senses which people can think of.